# Passing String from an activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass a String from an activity to a Fragment to later use it as a key for other things within the fragment but it comes back null. What am I doing wrong? here is code of the activity where my fragments sits

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_page);

        //this bit works fine, but later I also want to take string username and pass it to fragment
        username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        TextView welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        welcome.setText("Welcome, " + username);
    }

    public void flipTab(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_profile:
                fragment = new MyProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_edit:
                //another fragment here later
                break;
            case R.id.btn_colleges:
                fragment = new CollegeFragment();
                break;
        }
        //here I want to take the String username that came from the other activity and pass it to fragment
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("username", username);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fr, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment I am having trouble with

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private String text;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_profile, container, false);

        TextView example = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.ex);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            text = getArguments().getString("username");
        } else {
            example.setText(text);
            System.out.println("String=" + text);
        }

        Button signOut = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.user_sign_out);
        signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Logged out");
                logOut();
            }
        });

        return myFragmentView;
    }

    public void logOut() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I am new to fragments so sorry if I overlooked something extremely obvious. But I tried a few things and they seem to return null regardless. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So `getArguments().getString("username")` returns null, you say, which was not null at ` args.putString("username", username)`?

Comment: You appear to be attaching and retrieving the arguments correctly. I notice that you're not loading a `Fragment` in your code when `UserPage` starts, but only upon a click. Do you happen to have one defined in the layout with a `<fragment>` tag? Or is there some other content visible when that `Activity` starts?

Comment: @MikeM. you might be right, because the way I load it first is just defined in XML name tag.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a `<fragment>` in your layout, you can't pass arguments to that instance, because it will be loaded automagically for you. (You also wouldn't be able to remove or replace that one later, in code.) What you can do is change that `<fragment>` to a `<FrameLayout>`, remove the `android:name`/`class` attribute on it, and then just load a `MyProfileFragment` yourself in code, at startup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways either by using Bundle or by passing argument in fragment calling method

Example

**By Bundle**

In Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and In the Fragment task

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```